# Vb.Net Accept Request Without Contet-Type definition

Tags: .net, vb.net, web, service

i deploy Web Service with Vb.Net,

the client call me without set Content-Type in Header (It's correct??)
How i can accept this request? Actually my server resp with http 415 server 
error..

Tnk!

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse my bad English.

The content-type is not mandatory. 
to accept the request you must create a Custom HTTP Modules that intercepts requests before they are rejected. 
With HTTP Modules you can set the content-type and to accept the request.

you can find an example on microsoft documentation

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673(v=vs.85).aspx